# coldFusion Regular Expression for "number tab tab"

Tags: regex, coldfusion

can someone help me with syntax please...

I am parsing a file and am expecting the end of a line to be "ANY number" and two tabs...

such as 3[tab][tab]

currently I'm using

```
if ( right( _myLine, 2 ) NEQ '#chr(9)##chr(9)#' )
```

And that works, EXCEPT I want to catch instances where there is a something OTHER than a number preceding that tab tab...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
if ( NOT REFind( "[0-9]\t\t", right(_myLine, 3 ) ) )
```

OR

```
if ( NOT REFind( "[0-9]\t\t$", _myLine ) )
```

You can use "\d" in place of "[0-9]".

Hope this helps.